# Abstract algebra question (1) order problem (2) ring problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be an abelian group and let a, b ∈ G have orders m and n respectively.
Suppose furthermore that gcd(m, n) = 1. Show that ab has order mn.

I noticed that if gcd(m,n) is not 1, then order of ab is smaller than mn.

Let R be any finite ring with unity. Show that every nonzero element of R is either a unit or a zero divisor

For this question, I am not sure how to start.

I guess for any a in R, we want to show either ab=1 or ab=0.

Comment: For the first question, think about this: Can $a^i b^j$ equal the identity without both $a^i$ and $b^j$ equalling the identity? For the second question, you haven't said what $b$ is.

Comment: I mean  b is just element in R.

Comment: I think you'll learn something if you are actually precise. It's too much to hope that if we choose some random element $b$ of $R$ that either $a$ times that $b$ equals $1$ or $a$ times that $b$ equals $0$. So what did you mean?

Answer (score 1):

## For problem (1):

Let $|ab|=t$, then $(ab)^{mn}=a^{mn}b^{mn}=(a^m)^n(b^n)^m=e.$ Thus $t$ divides $mn$. So $t \leq mn$. Furthermore $(ab)^t=e$ implies $a^t=b^{-t}$. Thus $|a^t|=|b^{-t}|$. But
$$|a^t|=\frac{m}{\gcd(m,t)}=\frac{n}{\gcd(n,t)}=|b^{-t}|.$$
This last expression says:
$$m | (n\gcd(m,t))$$ 
but $\gcd(m,n)=1$, so $m | \gcd(m,t)$. This implies $t=mk$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Likewise $t=np$ for some $p \in \mathbb{Z}$. But $\gcd(m,n)=1$ implies $mn | t$. Thus $mn \leq t$. Hence $t=mn$.

## For problem (2):

Let $R=\{a_1,a_2, \ldots ,a_n\}$. Let $a_1 \in R$ such that $a_1 \not \in \{ 1_R,0_R\}$. Now consider the map $x \to a_1x$.

If this is not injective then $\exists x,y \in R$ such that $x \neq y$ and $a_1x=a_1y$. But this gives $a_1(x-y) = 0$. Hence $a_1$ is a zero-divisor.

If this is injective (hence surjective as well due to finiteness) then $\exists x \in R$ such that $a_1x=1$. Then $a_1$ is a unit,

Comment: How can we guarantee that there exists such mapping from x to ax? and I don't quite understand your second explanantion. "If this is injective,~~" why is there x such that ax=1?

Comment: @Nancy the function $f:R \longrightarrow R$ given by $f(x)=a_{1}x$ is well-defined as rings are closed under multiplication. Regarding the "injective" idea--- if the function is injective then because this function is from finite set $R$ to itself it has to be onto as well. Since $R$ already has unity, thus by ontoness something must map to $1_{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

**For second question**,

Let $a\in R$ think $a,a^2,a^3...$. As $R$ is finite.

**Edit** (As AnuragA suggest)

We must have $a^i=a^j\implies a^j(a^{i-j}-1)=0$, if $a^{i-j}\neq 1$ then $a$ is zero divisior.

Comment: Oh, is it a proof for the second question? cause seems quite simple

Comment: This is not true. For example in $\mathbb Z_6$, every power of $3$ is $3$, never $1$ and never $0$.

Comment: @mesel here is a fix for your idea. By finiteness $\exists j,k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^{j}=a^{k}$. From this we can say $a^{k}(a^{j-k}-1)=0$. Now if the second term is $0$ then we have a unit, otherwise we have a zero divisor.

Comment: @AnuragA: You are right. thank you.

Comment: @AnuragA - beautiful fix! I think of the result the way you described in your answer (if an element is not a zerodivisor then multiplication by it is injective, hence surjective in finite case, hence it is a unit since 1 is in the image), but this argument explicitly constructs either the inverse or an element of the annihilator!